# Как выдернуть определенные узлы из XML с помощью XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML:

```
<ns1:FNSVipULResponse xmlns:ns1="urn://x-artefacts-fns-vipul-tosmv-ru/311-14/4.0.5" ИдДок="22ED0D32-F3F2-0693-E050-A8C0D3C81091">
    <ns1:СвЮЛ xmlns:fnst="urn://x-artefacts-fns/vipul-types/4.0.5" ДатаВып="2015-04-16" ДатаОГРН="2008-11-18" ИНН="7730592673" КПП="773001001" КодОПФ="12345" ОГРН="5087746429843" ПолнНаимОПФ="ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ" СпрОПФ="ОКОПФ">
        <ns1:СвНаимЮЛ НаимЮЛПолн="НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ 5087746429843" НаимЮЛСокр="СОКРАЩЕННОЕ НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ 5087746429843">
            <ns1:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
        </ns1:СвНаимЮЛ>
        <ns1:СвАдресЮЛ>
            <ns1:АдресРФ Дом="7" КодАдрКладр="770000000002990" КодРегион="77" Корпус="6">
                <fnst:Регион НаимРегион="МОСКВА" ТипРегион="ГОРОД" />
                <fnst:Улица НаимУлица="ФИЛЕВСКАЯ 2-Я" ТипУлица="УЛИЦА" />
                <fnst:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
            </ns1:АдресРФ>
        </ns1:СвАдресЮЛ>
        <ns1:СвОбрЮЛ ДатаОГРН="2008-11-18" ОГРН="5087746429843">
            <ns1:СпОбрЮЛ КодСпОбрЮЛ="11" НаимСпОбрЮЛ="ГОСУДАРСТВЕННАЯ РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ ЮРИДИЧЕСКОГО ЛИЦА ПРИ СОЗДАНИИ" />
            <ns1:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
        </ns1:СвОбрЮЛ>
        <ns1:СвРегОрг АдрРО="125373, Г.МОСКВА, ПОХОДНЫЙ ПРОЕЗД, ДОМОВЛАДЕНИЕ 3, СТР.2" КодНО="7733" НаимНО="МЕЖРАЙОННАЯ ИНСПЕКЦИЯ ФЕДЕРАЛЬНОЙ НАЛОГОВОЙ СЛУЖБЫ № 46 ПО Г. МОСКВЕ">
            <ns1:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
        </ns1:СвРегОрг>
        <ns1:СвУчетНО ДатаПостУч="2008-11-18" ИНН="7730592673" КПП="773001001">
            <ns1:СвНО КодНО="7730" НаимНО="ИНСПЕКЦИЯ ФЕДЕРАЛЬНОЙ НАЛОГОВОЙ СЛУЖБЫ № 30 ПО Г. МОСКВЕ" />
            <ns1:ГРНДата ГРН="2087764197948" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
        </ns1:СвУчетНО>
        <ns1:СвРегПФ ДатаРег="2008-11-19" РегНомПФ="087806035495">
            <ns1:СвОргПФ КодПФ="087806" НаимПФ="ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОЕ УЧРЕЖДЕНИЕ - ГЛАВНОЕ УПРАВЛЕНИЕ ПЕНСИОННОГО ФОНДА РФ №2 УПРАВЛЕНИЕ №2 МУНИЦИПАЛЬНЫЙ РАЙОН ФИЛЕВСКИЙ ПАРК" />
            <ns1:ГРНДата ГРН="2087764333402" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-20" />
        </ns1:СвРегПФ>
        <ns1:СвРегФСС ДатаРег="2008-11-19" РегНомФСС="772803546077281">
            <ns1:СвОргФСС КодФСС="7728" НаимФСС="ФИЛИАЛ №28 ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОГО УЧРЕЖДЕНИЯ - МОСКОВСКОГО РЕГИОНАЛЬНОГО ОТДЕЛЕНИЯ ФОНДА СОЦИАЛЬНОГО СТРАХОВАНИЯ РОССИЙСКОЙ ФЕДЕРАЦИИ" />
            <ns1:ГРНДата ГРН="2087764310490" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-20" />
        </ns1:СвРегФСС>
        <ns1:СвУстКап НаимВидКап="УСТАВНЫЙ КАПИТАЛ" СумКап="10000.0000">
            <ns1:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
        </ns1:СвУстКап>
        <ns1:СведДолжнФЛ>
            <ns1:ГРНДатаПерв ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
            <ns1:СвФЛ Имя="ИМЯ 87746823009337" Отчество="ОТЧЕСТВО 87746823009337" Фамилия="ФАМИЛИЯ 87746823009337">
                <fnst:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
            </ns1:СвФЛ>
            <ns1:СвДолжн ВидДолжн="02" НаимВидДолжн="РУКОВОДИТЕЛЬ ЮРИДИЧЕСКОГО ЛИЦА" НаимДолжн="ГЕНЕРАЛЬНЫЙ ДИРЕКТОР">
                <ns1:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
            </ns1:СвДолжн>
        </ns1:СведДолжнФЛ>
        <ns1:СвУчредит>
            <ns1:УчрФЛ>
                <ns1:СвФЛ Имя="ИМЯ 87746823009338" Отчество="ОТЧЕСТВО 87746823009338" Фамилия="ФАМИЛИЯ 87746823009338">
                    <fnst:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
                </ns1:СвФЛ>
            </ns1:УчрФЛ>
        </ns1:СвУчредит>
        <ns1:СвОКВЭД>
            <ns1:СвОКВЭДОсн КодОКВЭД="17.30" НаимОКВЭД="ОТДЕЛКА ТКАНЕЙ И ТЕКСТИЛЬНЫХ ИЗДЕЛИЙ">
                <fnst:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
            </ns1:СвОКВЭДОсн>
            <ns1:СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="18.22" НаимОКВЭД="ПРОИЗВОДСТВО ВЕРХНЕЙ ОДЕЖДЫ">
                <fnst:ГРНДата ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18" />
            </ns1:СвОКВЭДДоп>
        </ns1:СвОКВЭД>
        <ns1:СвЗапЕГРЮЛ ГРН="5087746429843" ДатаЗап="2008-11-18" ИдЗап="87746823009334">
            <ns1:ВидЗап КодСПВЗ="11201" НаимВидЗап="ГОСУДАРСТВЕННАЯ РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ ЮРИДИЧЕСКОГО ЛИЦА ПРИ СОЗДАНИИ" />
            <ns1:СвРегОрг КодНО="7746" НаимНО="МЕЖРАЙОННАЯ ИНСПЕКЦИЯ ФЕДЕРАЛЬНОЙ НАЛОГОВОЙ СЛУЖБЫ № 46 ПО Г. МОСКВЕ" />
            <ns1:СведПредДок>
                <ns1:НаимДок>ЗАЯВЛЕНИЕ (С ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯМИ)</ns1:НаимДок>
                <ns1:ДатаДок>2008-11-11</ns1:ДатаДок>
            </ns1:СведПредДок>
            <ns1:СведПредДок>
                <ns1:НаимДок>УСТАВ</ns1:НаимДок>
                <ns1:ДатаДок>2008-11-11</ns1:ДатаДок>
            </ns1:СведПредДок>
            <ns1:СведПредДок>
                <ns1:НаимДок>ПРОТОКОЛ</ns1:НаимДок>
                <ns1:ДатаДок>2008-11-11</ns1:ДатаДок>
            </ns1:СведПредДок>
            <ns1:СведПредДок>
                <ns1:НаимДок>ЗАЯВЛЕНИЕ О ПЕРЕХОДЕ НА УПРОЩЕННУЮ СИСТЕМУ НАЛОГООБЛОЖЕНИЯ</ns1:НаимДок>
                <ns1:ДатаДок>2008-11-11</ns1:ДатаДок>
            </ns1:СведПредДок>
            <ns1:СведПредДок>
                <ns1:НаимДок>ЗАПРОС, КВИТАНЦИЯ</ns1:НаимДок>
                <ns1:ДатаДок>2008-11-11</ns1:ДатаДок>
            </ns1:СведПредДок>
            <ns1:СведПредДок>
                <ns1:НаимДок>КОП. УСТ</ns1:НаимДок>
                <ns1:ДатаДок>2008-11-11</ns1:ДатаДок>
            </ns1:СведПредДок>
            <ns1:СведПредДок>
                <ns1:НаимДок>УВЕД</ns1:НаимДок>
                <ns1:ДатаДок>2008-11-11</ns1:ДатаДок>
            </ns1:СведПредДок>
            <ns1:СведПредДок>
                <ns1:НаимДок>ДОКУМЕНТ ОБ УПЛАТЕ ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОЙ ПОШЛИНЫ</ns1:НаимДок>
                <ns1:ДатаДок>2008-11-11</ns1:ДатаДок>
            </ns1:СведПредДок>
            <ns1:СвСвид ДатаВыдСвид="2008-11-18" Номер="010419289" Серия="77" />
        </ns1:СвЗапЕГРЮЛ>
        <ns1:СвЗапЕГРЮЛ ГРН="2087764197948" ДатаЗап="2008-11-18" ИдЗап="87746823009339">
            <ns1:ВидЗап КодСПВЗ="13200" НаимВидЗап="ВНЕСЕНИЕ В ЕДИНЫЙ ГОСУДАРСТВЕННЫЙ РЕЕСТР ЮРИДИЧЕСКИХ ЛИЦ СВЕДЕНИЙ ОБ УЧЕТЕ ЮРИДИЧЕСКОГО ЛИЦА В НАЛОГОВОМ ОРГАНЕ" />
            <ns1:СвРегОрг КодНО="7746" НаимНО="МЕЖРАЙОННАЯ ИНСПЕКЦИЯ ФЕДЕРАЛЬНОЙ НАЛОГОВОЙ СЛУЖБЫ № 46 ПО Г. МОСКВЕ" />
        </ns1:СвЗапЕГРЮЛ>
        <ns1:СвЗапЕГРЮЛ ГРН="2087764310490" ДатаЗап="2008-11-20" ИдЗап="87746825001847">
            <ns1:ВидЗап КодСПВЗ="13400" НаимВидЗап="ВНЕСЕНИЕ В ЕДИНЫЙ ГОСУДАРСТВЕННЫЙ РЕЕСТР ЮРИДИЧЕСКИХ ЛИЦ СВЕДЕНИЙ О РЕГИСТРАЦИИ ЮРИДИЧЕСКОГО ЛИЦА В КАЧЕСТВЕ СТРАХОВАТЕЛЯ В ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬНОМ ОРГАНЕ ФОНДА СОЦИАЛЬНОГО СТРАХОВАНИЯ РОССИЙСКОЙ ФЕДЕРАЦИИ" />
            <ns1:СвРегОрг КодНО="7746" НаимНО="МЕЖРАЙОННАЯ ИНСПЕКЦИЯ ФЕДЕРАЛЬНОЙ НАЛОГОВОЙ СЛУЖБЫ № 46 ПО Г. МОСКВЕ" />
        </ns1:СвЗапЕГРЮЛ>
        <ns1:СвЗапЕГРЮЛ ГРН="2087764333402" ДатаЗап="2008-11-20" ИдЗап="87746825004279">
            <ns1:ВидЗап КодСПВЗ="13300" НаимВидЗап="ВНЕСЕНИЕ В ЕДИНЫЙ ГОСУДАРСТВЕННЫЙ РЕЕСТР ЮРИДИЧЕСКИХ ЛИЦ СВЕДЕНИЙ О РЕГИСТРАЦИИ ЮРИДИЧЕСКОГО ЛИЦА В КАЧЕСТВЕ СТРАХОВАТЕЛЯ В ТЕРРИТОРИАЛЬНОМ ОРГАНЕ ПЕНСИОННОГО ФОНДА РОССИЙСКОЙ ФЕДЕРАЦИИ" />
            <ns1:СвРегОрг КодНО="7746" НаимНО="МЕЖРАЙОННАЯ ИНСПЕКЦИЯ ФЕДЕРАЛЬНОЙ НАЛОГОВОЙ СЛУЖБЫ № 46 ПО Г. МОСКВЕ" />
        </ns1:СвЗапЕГРЮЛ>
    </ns1:СвЮЛ>
</ns1:FNSVipULResponse>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="urn://x-artefacts-fns-vipip-tosmv-ru/311-15/4.0.5" xmlns:fnst="urn://x-artefacts-fns/vipip-types/4.0.5">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="ns1:FNSVipULResponse/ns1:СвЮЛ">        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:СвНаимЮЛ"/>        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ns1:СвНаимЮЛ">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ns1:СвАдресЮЛ">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ns1:СвУчетНО">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ns1:СведДолжнФЛ">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output некорректный. Как получить определенные ноды по определенному тегу (ns1:СвНаимЮЛ, ns1:СвАдресЮЛ, ns1:СвУчетНО, ns1:СведДолжнФЛ)? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить проблему. Дело было в префиксе тега (ns1). Из-за него не удавалось преобразовать XML.

Корректный XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns1="urn://x-artefacts-fns-vipip-tosmv-ru/311-15/4.0.5"
    xmlns:fnst="urn://x-artefacts-fns/vipip-types/4.0.5">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        xmlns:ns1="urn://x-artefacts-fns-vipul-tosmv-ru/311-14/4.0.5"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='FNSVipULResponse']/*[local-name()='СвЮЛ']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()='СвНаимЮЛ']"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()='СвАдресЮЛ']"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()='СвУчетНО']"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()='СведДолжнФЛ']"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```